# How to change style when visitor tabs to select element?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tags, anchor

Is there a way to have the anchor tag change its style (background image) when the user tabs to it? I tried setting the CSS style on a:hover and a:active but it doesn't seem to work.

Also, this anchor tag is in a table cell. Basically I have this style for changing the look of the row the user is about to select any I want the row to apply the same style when user tabs to the anchor tag.

If I need to use jQuery, then a sample would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the [`:focus` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes).

```
a:focus
{
  /* whatever styles you feel like */
  outline: 1px solid #F00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in javascript using the focus event.

```
$('#your-anchor-tag-selector').focus(function() {
  $(this).css({'background-image':'images/your-image.jpg)'});
});
```

Comment: -1 because you shouldn't be using JS for styling that simple CSS can accomplish. Additionally, this will leave the styles present after the user tabs away from the selected element.

Comment: @Pete No worries, I assumed that it wasn't as simple as :focus seeing as how you mentioned you tried :hover already.